# Сортировка материалов. PHP, MySQL, jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, mysql

Всем привет. Я хочу сделать сортировку, для примера скажем, новостей. Т.е. блоки, которые мы мышкой перетаскиваем и меняем их последовательность вывода. Несколько вопросов.

1. Какой хороший jQuery скрипт есть для подобных операций.
2. Как это будет выглядеть в БД? Я подозреваю, что надо создать еще одну колонку и там уже хранить какое то значение.

В общем так я смутно представляю, как такое делать. Может кто расскажет в общих деталях, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). В блоках, в каком-нибудь атрибуте, держите id новости из таблицы. После завершения сортировки, скажем по нажатию кнопки или другому событию, собираете последовательно в массив все id-шники и обновляете данные в таблице, т.е. то доп. поле, которое содержит порядковый номер вывода этой новости. Индекс элемента массива + 1 = этот порядковый номер

Comment: Не совсем понял последнюю часть вашего ответа, как в БД хранить)

Comment: Попробую объяснить "на пальцах")) После сортировки у вас к примеру такой массив:

    $newsArr = array(12,50,2,7);

Это массив id-шников. Теперь в цикле апдейтим записи в таблице. 
    
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($newsArr); $i++) {
        // запрос
        $query = "UPDATE `news` SET `sequence` = $i WHERE `news_id` = '$newsArr[$i]'";
    }

Comment: Что ж. Спасибо. Попробую

Comment: Что ж тут пробовать? Делать надо ))) Как собрать в массив id, сможете сами или подсказать?

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы подсказали :)

Comment: [Вот примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/mFV4J/)